# 'attention from/in/of' the (research) community?

Tags: prepositions

I want to write the following sentence: 'Despite the growing attention of the research community, however, there exist several open issues.' I am, however, not sure about the right preposition.

'attention of' is probably not an option but is it better to say here 'attention from' or 'attention in'? [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewUnsolvedquery.php?idThread=264276&idForum=1&lang=de&lp=ende) tells me that, in general, it should be 'attention from'. But I wonder if in the case of a community, as in the example, it should not be 'attention in'?

Comment: _Attention from_ treats the attention as coming from the community, which is located outside of whatever is being attended to (which, by the way, is not mentioned here, so it might clarify matters to refer to it). _Attention in_ treats the community as a container, and the attention is located there, along with the members; again, the focus of the attention is unmentioned. Which one you use depends on which way you're looking at the "research community" in relation to your mcguffin. It's a [metaphor](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Metaphors.pdf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine as it is. (*Attention from* might have been appropriate if you'd omitted the definite article before *growing*.)

Comment: Sorry, I am confused. You say that it's fine as it is but I'm using 'of' in the question. But then you say that in order to use 'of' I have to omit the article. I don't understand...

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Answer now amended.